# Why string==string comparison failing?

Tags: c++, string, comparison

Following is the code snippet of what I did, can some body help me where I have wrongly coded it:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void modifyName(string &name)
{
    size_t sep = string::npos;
    sep = name.find_first_of(".");

    if(sep != string::npos) { name[sep] = '\0'; }
}

int main()
{
    string name("test.rtl");
    string someName("test");
    modifyName(name);

    if( someName == name ) //Failing??
        cout<<"MATCHED"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a short, self contained example

Comment: When I tried debugging this I got to know that cout<<name.c_str()<<" ... "<< name<<endl;  outputs: test ... testrtl     so cout operator '<<' works differently on string and char* objects. Just felt it will worth sharing :).

Comment: When you use `name.c_str()` you are creating a c-style string from the `std::string` - c-style strings are null-terminated. As you had inserted a null into the middle of the string, this terminates it when c-styled. But a `std::string` can contain any value, including null - however a null is generally not printable, so would not be output... but would also not signify the end of the character sequence.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As others have said, the strings don't match, as one is `"test\0rtl"` and the other is `"test"`. It's fine to use `==` for `std::string` comparison, as the operator is overloaded for string equality. To do what you want, you should try replacing

```
if(sep != string::npos) { name[sep] = '\0'; }
```

with

```
if(sep != string::npos) { name.resize(sep); }
```

Comment: +1 as using resize rather than my suggestion (substr) should at least be faster due to not using assignment.

Comment: @pankiii: I wouldn't call this a "workaround" - it's the right way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Why resize rather than erase? Though in this case you'll get the same result.

Comment: @AlefSin: std::string::erase is more general, so it might be marginally slower to work out that there are no characters that need to be copied from the end of the string. As you say, no substantial difference though.

Comment: @Micheal ya pardon my language.. its the perfect way to truncate strings after some character.

Answer (score 13):

It's failing, because they are not the same.. You haven't "cut" the string, just changed a char in it.

`someName` is `test`, while `name` is `test\0rtl` ( `std::string` allows you to have zero-chars(`'\0'`) inside )

To cut the string, you need to use `std::string::resize` or to self-assign the substring, using `std::string::substr`. I'd recommend `resize`.

Answer (score 9):

In this line

```
if(sep != string::npos) { name[sep] = '\0'; }
```

You are modifying the string to be `"test\0rtl"`. A std::basic_string can contain null characters, so the strings are not the same. You could use `substr` to truncate the string instead:

```
if(sep != string::npos) { name = name.substr(sep); }
```

This will cause the string to become `"test"`, which should (!!) compare correctly.